# Delete or add cell from TableViewDataSource when it's a separate Swift file

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

**Setup:**

I have a standard `TableViewController.swift` that serves as a tableview delegate, and a **separate** file called `TableViewDataSource.swift` that serves as the dataSource.

For the top section of the tableview, I have a series of buttons inside the cells, which has a close action. The goal of this section is to serve as notifications that the user could dismiss: [image]

Each button has a tag which is the `indexPath.row`.

**Problem**

My problem is this. I would like to animate the deletion of this cell once the user taps the "x" button. It's handled by this:

```
func tappedOnExit(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print ("tapped on \(sender.tag)")

}
```

However, to officially delete a row, I need to call

`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

As noted above, since the button function `tappedOnExit` is in my  `dataSource`, which is a **separate file** from my viewController, I am unable to call something like `self.tableView. deleteRowsAtIndexPaths`

Suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add  observer (notifications center) in viewcontroller file.

And on click of "x" you can call post notifications  from data source file.

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(deleteRow, object: indexPath.row)

Comment: This is definitely a direction I could take to communicate between my `delegate` and `dataSource`. If there is no more organic way to do this via default tableView methods, I'll probably do this. Thanks for chiming in.

Comment: By sender of "x" you can find superView and from it you can call tableview's methods

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are catching the fact that the close button has been hit in the wrong place.  Your data source should be a very simple interface into the model behind your table view.  It should not be concerned with things like which cells are tapped and when.

Your UIButtons should probably be delegating their clicks, not to the data source, but to the table view itself. The table view could then determine which row was closed and remove that row.

Comment: Thanks Scott. I think this is probably the better approach to what I am currently doing. I can't quite wrap my mind around how I could handle the button tap in my `delegate` and not `dataSource`. At the moment, the button's target is registered in `cellForRow indexPath` (which is in the `dataSource`). Rather than doing it this way, where would you recommend?

Comment: The full method signature is `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`.. Presumably in that call you have the `tableView`?  In that case you should be able to set the target of the UI button in the cell that is created to be the tableView with an action of something like `closeButtonHit`.  The trick in that method will be to find the cell whose close button was hit by running through the table view's cells and finding one who button matches the sender.

Comment: We're on the same page. That's what I did in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`. I (1) registered the button to have the same tag as the `indexPath.row` by doing: `cell.exitButton.tag = indexPath.row` and then (2) I did `cell.exitButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tappedOnExit(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)` As you mentioned, the downside to this is my click logic is inside my `dataSource`, and I need to do something hacky like use a notification to get it to my `delegate`

Comment: Instead of `cell.exitButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tappedOnExit(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)` use `cell.exitButton.addTarget(tableView, action: #selector(tappedOnExit(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)` and move your `tappedOnExit` to the tableView instead of the data source.

Comment: Great suggestion. Unfortunately when I moved `tappedOnExit` to my `tableView`, I get the error in my `dataSource` for "use of resolved identifier"  Here is the line of coding that's throwing the error: `cell.exitButton.addTarget(tableView, action: #selector(tappedOnExit(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should either use delegation here or find an alternative approach that does not limit you in this way. Check out delegation from the below resources:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html

https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/pass-data-with-delegation-in-swift-86f6bc5d0894

Answer (score -1):

You don't call `commitEditingStyle` yourself, the `TableView` sends that method. You just call `deleteRowAtIndexPath`: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment. My problem is, since my `dataSource` is a separate file, I can't access something like `self.tableView.delete...` In fact, I cannot access `self.tableView`

Comment: Are you creating your datasource in TableViewController ? if so, just pass and keep a reference

Comment: I do keep a ref to my `dataSource` in my `TableViewController`. However, I still register my button logic `cellForRow indexPath`. Any recommendation is appreciated. (Also, did not downvote)